# Errors simplexml - Complicated URL

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to display items from an XML feed on a page

This is my code...

```
$feed = 'http://awebsite.co.uk/directory/rssfeed.php?thecondition=(title%20LIKE%20'%british%'%20OR%20description%20LIKE%20'%british%')';
$xml = simplexml_load_file("$feed");
if ( $xml->channel->item !='' ) {
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) { 
echo '<li><a href="' . $item->link . '">' . $item->title . '</a></li>';
}  
} 
else { echo 'None'; }
```

However, due to the complicated feed URL it is giving lots of errors.

Note: I have changed the domain in the URL for this example.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Can't judge anything without seeing the XML source first but if it's a standard RSS channel file you should be iterating through your items something like this:

```
$items = $xml->xpath('/channel/item');
foreach ($items as $item) { 
    echo '<li><a href="' . $item->link . '">' . $item->title . '</a></li>';
}
```

Also the initial condition: `if ( $xml->channel->item !='' ) {/*...*/}`  isn't really going to work.

Comment: Thanks... I will take that into consideration, but the error I am getting is to do with the complicated feed URL.

I am getting the following error 4 times...

Warning: Division by zero in /home/website/public_html/wp-content/themes/WFclarity/search.php on line 78

Comment: Add proper quotes to define your variable. Start and end with double quotes since the URL has single quotes in it. `$feed="http://...../?thecondition=(title%20LIKE%20'%british%'%20OR%20description%20LIKE%20'%british%')"`

Comment: That's great but simplexml turns that URL into

    thecondition=(title%2520LIKE%2520'%25british%25'%2520OR%2520description%2520LIKE%2520'%25british%25')

Comment: It seems that it tries to `urlencode` an already enconded string. Replace '%20' with spaces in the original URL and see what happens.

Comment: I think it's the % around each side of the british that's causing the problem

Comment: Thanks for your help... 

I added the feed url to a variable called $feedurl

Then I used $feed = urldecode($feedurl); 

Then used $feed as before, and it worked, cheers!

Comment: Glad to hear. Please also note one thing: I'dont know if the original feed supplier `rssfeed.php` script is yours, but the `thecondition` parameter is a nasty SQL injection entry point.